# Dashboard of historical data in iot_datasourse

Tags: sensors, visualization, node-red

I have historical data stored in an SQL database as date in the format (2017.10.27 12:00:25) and the corresponding temperature in the format (26.55). I am using the node iot_datasourse to show the data and the debug message shows the time and the corresponding temperature, but the dashboard doesn't show any graphic.

The flow nodes are as follows, I would appreciate some help

```
 [  
   {  
      "id":"3eeefbee.524fa4",
      "type":"iot-datasource",
      "z":"a287c70.b313638",
      "name":"Temperature_historical_data",
      "tstampField":"tstamp",
      "dataField":"data",
      "disableDiscover":false,
      "x":760,
      "y":1580,
      "wires":[  
         [  
            "c63ec7ee.45bef8"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":"19f7ecaf.b15d73",
      "type":"function",
      "z":"a287c70.b313638",
      "name":"Temp",
      "func":"var p =msg.payload;\n\nfor(var i=0;i<p.length;i++){\n    var dUnix =Date.parse(p[i].Datum);\n    node.send({payload:{data:p[i].Temp, tstamp:dUnix}});\n}\nreturn;",
      "outputs":1,
      "noerr":0,
      "x":550,
      "y":1580,
      "wires":[  
         [  
            "3eeefbee.524fa4",
            "9ac5be07.61cb7"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":"3ff59acb.6fa9d6",
      "type":"MSSQL",
      "z":"a287c70.b313638",
      "mssqlCN":"e1823c68.173aa",
      "name":"database_sql",
      "query":"",
      "outField":"payload",
      "x":390,
      "y":1580,
      "wires":[  
         [  
            "19f7ecaf.b15d73"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":"df2d6585.9e5338",
      "type":"inject",
      "z":"a287c70.b313638",
      "name":"",
      "topic":"",
      "payload":"SELECT * FROM [test].[Temp]",
      "payloadType":"str",
      "repeat":"",
      "crontab":"",
      "once":false,
      "onceDelay":0.1,
      "x":170,
      "y":1580,
      "wires":[  
         [  
            "3ff59acb.6fa9d6"
         ]
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":"9ac5be07.61cb7",
      "type":"debug",
      "z":"a287c70.b313638",
      "name":"",
      "active":true,
      "tosidebar":true,
      "console":false,
      "tostatus":false,
      "complete":"false",
      "x":730,
      "y":1500,
      "wires":[  

      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":"c63ec7ee.45bef8",
      "type":"debug",
      "z":"a287c70.b313638",
      "name":"",
      "active":true,
      "tosidebar":true,
      "console":false,
      "tostatus":false,
      "complete":"false",
      "x":970,
      "y":1500,
      "wires":[  

      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":"e1823c68.173aa",
      "type":"MSSQL-CN",
      "z":"",
      "name":"SQL",
      "server":"localhost",
      "encyption":true,
      "database":"test"
   }
]
```

Comment: Your posted flow is incomplete

Comment: Also please don't cross post questions to multiple Node-RED forums, it's normally the same people answering on both https://discourse.nodered.org/t/iot-datasource-is-not-showing-the-graph/1716/6